# How to transpose multiple rows and columns (with blank cells) into two columns without any blank cells?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm re-organizing a data set with multiple rows and columns that include: several email addresses and names in each cell and on the bottom row it only includes one email address and one name.

I would like to shift all blank cells so that each email and name are side by side (two columns) and going down without mixing anything.

How I want to re-organize the rows and columns:

[image: How I want to re-organize the rows and columns]

I've tried using add-ons such as: Split Names and Remove Blank Rows, but it can't automatically detect that it is the email addresses and names from one group.

If I use the following formula, it only takes all email addresses on the top and the names on the bottom as well as the blank spaces.

```
=transpose(G51:N53)
```

Could anyone help me out reorganize so that the email addresses and the names be aligned side by side in two columns like this?

```
sylvester.stalone@gmail.com | Sylvester Stalone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={"EMAIL", "NAME"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:E<>"", "♠"&B3:E&"♦"&F3:I, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦")))}
```

[image: 0]